# Change URL without reloading page in Google Chrome

Tags: applescript, whatsapp

I use this AppleScript with FileMaker to send WhatsApp To my company staff.

The problem is that Google Chrome reloads the page each time I change the phone number.

Is there are a way to just change the URL without reloading the page in Google Chrome?

AppleScript code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell window 1 to tell active tab
        set URL to "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55555text=MESSEGE);"
        delay 0.2
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Setting the URL of the tab loads that URL - what result are you expecting?

Comment: Do you want to change the page or should it stay as is, just with a different Text in the search bar?

Comment: hi, i send to the Chrome window which open and login web,whatsapp,  phone number and text through this link "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0000000000$text=MESSEGE);" the problem that not all numbers register at phone contact list so each time i send the link to chrome page, it start to load from scratch, i want to go direct to open chat part in html without loading the whole page.